# How to keep the names of the data frame variables while unlisting?

Tags: r, list

I try to unlist a list that contains multiple data frames while keeping the variable names. The list items (the data frames) don't have names but the variables inside the data frames do.

For example:

```
l = list(data.frame(a = c(1,3), b =c(2,6)), data.frame(c=c(3,5), d=c(6,7 )))
```

And I unlist it into one data frame using

```
l1 = c(l) %>% map(t) %>% map(~ split(., 1:nrow(.))) %>% unlist(recursive = F) %>% data.frame()
```

which produces

```
  c.1..3. c.2..6. c.3..5. c.6..7.
1       1       2       3       6
2       3       6       5       7
```

What I want is

```
        a       b       c       d
1       1       2       3       6
2       3       6       5       7
```

One solution I can think of is to rename the variables afterwards using a `for` loop with something like `names(l1) = names(l[[i]])` then output all the names as one vector:

`[1] "a"   "b"   "c"  "d"`

but I haven't got any luck with this one.

Comment: for the updated post looks like you need `do.call(cbind, l)` ?

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks, yes, seems I learn R the hard way.

Comment: Although the problem solved, just a curiosity, is it possible to add multiple names to a vector using a `for` loop and `c`?

Comment: not clear to me. You could ask a new question with an example.